# Copy a sharepoint list from a prod to dev

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, powershell

What is the best way to copy a sharepoint list from one server to the other?
Saving site as template and trying to move it is not working for me.

And also if I use export method, does it copy or move the list?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save list as template instead of saving whole site. Just open list settings and choose *Save list as template*, where you can choose to include content in template. Then you can download such list as a file from List Template Gallery and upload it to List Template Gallery of destination site. Lastly you only need to create new list based on this template.

[More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

**UPDATE:**

If it doesn't work for you, you can try [`Export-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ff607895.aspx) and [`Import-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ff607613.aspx) cmdlets in PowerShell.

On source server:

`Export-SPWeb -Identity <SiteURL> -Path .\export.cmp -ItemUrl <URL of List> -IncludeVersions All -Verbose`

On target server:

`Import-SPWeb <SiteURL> -Path .\export.cmp`

You can do this from Central Administration too.

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ee428301.aspx)

Comment: Yes but when doing that I get error. Checked the logs and there's nothing I find useful. Is there any other way?

Comment: I updated my answer.